# What is the difference between using Route and without in Web Api Controller?

Tags: c#

I have this code in Web Api controller in C#. One is with `Route` attribute and another is without.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetReport")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(){
      // code removed for brevity
    }
```

and another version is

```
    [HttpGet("GetReport")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(){
      // code removed for brevity
    }
```

They both works the same, is it?

Comment: This link can help you https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @MeysamAsadi, I can see that is talking about route atttribute. I am asking if I don't use route attribute and use put it is HttpGet attribute, are they both the same?

Comment: No, if you do not use  route atttribute you must define the path in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport()` (without any annotation at all) will probably also work (it certainly does on ASP.Net Core; your mileage might vary).  REASON: Routing by "Convention'.  USEFUL ARTICLE: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convention-routing-vs-attribute-routing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They both works the same, is it?

Yes, though you might prefer to just use the `HttpGet("...")` as it's neater to use one attribute instead of two. Personally I don't use Route, and I fully specify all routes in a HttpXxx, purely because finding the relevant code when some/page/url/blah is crashing, is a matter of doing Ctrl-F for the route as presented in the browser address bar (minus any parameter values). That's a lot harder to do if your route is broken up across RoutePrefix/Route

Comment: If there is one parameter, it will be  `[HttpGet("ReportRecipient/Id")]` and two parameters will be `[HttpGet("ReportRecipient/Name/Email")]` and for POST,      `[HttpPost("ReportRecipient/Add")]`?

Comment: Those examples just state a static route. If there are parameters to the method then they will need to be presented in curly braces; `ReportRecipient/{name}/{email}` etc. Yes, that's how it is for POST. There are plenty of other standard verbs too; PUT, PATCH and DELETE are common